# Appropriate statistical test to test if probabilities are accurate

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Prob    Outcome
0.09    0
0.10    0
0.10    0
0.11    1
0.84    1
0.99    1
0.86    1
0.78    1
0.86    1
0.00    0
etc.
```

i.e. a bunch a probabilities each with a single test. What statisitcal test should I use to test the hypothesis that the probabilities are correct?

**Further details**: The data points are *combat probabilities* from the game Civilization IV, and I have over 3000 of them in my set. Thus, each probaility is generated using some unknown formula from different input data, depending on the relative strengths of the units in that battle.

It has been suggested that the outcomes do not accurately reflect the probabilities given: for instance, the computer player wins more often that it should, based on the probabilites displayed, which is what we want to test.

So there is a link insofar as we assume the probabilities displayed are generated using the same formula for each line. It's this unknown formula that we want to test for consistency with the actual results.

Answer (score 9):

One idea would be to calculate the [log-loss](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss) of the probabilities, relative to the outcome.  If the log-loss is low, the probabilities closely match the outcome. Another idea would be to bin the probabilities into quartiles or deciles, and find the average probability and average outcome in each bin.

Can you share the dataset?  It seems very interesting.

/edit: Here's some examples.  First we load the data and the packages in R:

```
library(Metrics)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ROCR)
dat <- read.table('http://ge.tt/api/1/files/9vPYIdf/0/blob?download')
names(dat) <- c('prob', 'outcome')
```

Then we calculate [area under the ROC Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic), to see how well the probabilities separate the classes:

```
> auc(dat$outcome, dat$prob)
[1] 0.9179451
```

This AUC is high, but not perfect.  It also helps to plot the probability densities by class and the ROC curve itself:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=prob, fill=factor(outcome))) + geom_density(alpha=.2)
p <- prediction(dat$prob, dat$outcome)
plot(performance(p, "tpr", "fpr"), main="ROC Curve", colorize=TRUE)
```

[image: Class density]
[image: ROC]

Additionally, we can calculate log-loss, which measure how well the probabilities fit the logisitic function:

```
> logLoss(dat$outcome, dat$prob)
[1] 0.3187371
```

By this measure, the probabilities are pretty good.  We can make a smoothed scatterplot of outcomes vs probabilities, which shows us that the probabilities follow a pretty straight line:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=prob, y=outcome)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

[image: log]

This is why the logloss isn't closer to zero-- the probabilities follow a straight line, rather than a logistic curve.

Finally, you can bin the probabilities, and look at the predicted vs actual rates.

```
dat <- dat[order(dat$prob),]
dat$decile <- unlist(lapply(1:10, rep, nrow(dat)/10))
bins <- data.table(dat)[,lapply(.SD, mean), by='decile']
> bins
    decile      prob    outcome
 1:      1 0.0445977 0.04885057
 2:      2 0.2684770 0.32471264
 3:      3 0.4650000 0.44540230
 4:      4 0.6441092 0.65229885
 5:      5 0.7639943 0.75287356
 6:      6 0.8855172 0.89942529
 7:      7 0.9654310 0.96551724
 8:      8 0.9896839 1.00000000
 9:      9 0.9977874 1.00000000
10:     10 1.0000000 1.00000000
```

A plot of predicted (black) vs actual (red) shows that the predicted probabilities closely match the actual probabilities:

```
ggplot(bins, aes(x=decile)) + geom_line(aes(y=prob), col='black') + geom_line(aes(y=outcome), col='red')
```

[image: PvA]

I suspect that Civ IV players (myself included) tend to remember distinctly the few times a 97% or 98% battle goes the wrong way, which makes such losses seem more common than they actually are.  In a long game, with many hundreds of battles, you are going to lose quiete a few times, even when the odds are 90%+ in your favor.

Comment: Sure, file is at http://ge.tt/9vPYIdf/v/0

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used R before but maybe I'll check it out if I get some time. I'm also not previously familiar with ROC curves or log-loss, so I have some learning to do. I was really thinking of something along the lines of a test-statistic to use with a hypothesis test. I guess I could run some simulations using random outcomes given the list of probabilities, and use that to give 95% confidence bounds for the total expected wins.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you start with visualisation. Plot the (binned) rate of success for each probability against the probability.

Comment: OK, here it is binned at 1% intervals. What now? http://i.imgur.com/xfyCI5o.png

Comment: Well, after viewing the data you may be in a position to decide whether there are questions that you would like the data to help you answer. From the look of the plot in Glen_b's answer, your probabilities are pretty good. Do you really need to do any more?

Answer (score 1):

edit:

Actually given your plot there, immediately we see that the distribution is about what it should be

[image: plot of binned success probabilities]

I'd further suggest looking at a plot of the difference between the arcsin of the square root of the success rate in each interval and the arcsin of the square root of claimed probability (evaluated at the mean probability in each interval) plotted against the probability, which should look like horizontal "bar" of dots scattered around zero.  You can also add error-bars to each point, since the standard deviation should be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4n_i}}$ (where the number of trials in the $i$-th point would be $n_i$), so if you put vertical error bars on each point at $\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i}}$, about 95% of the error bars should cover zero. If there's a region where they usually don't include zero, that would indicate a bias.

---

Original:

The alternative that "the computer player wins more often than it should" is relatively easy to test with this data - you can just compute a mean and variance for the expected number of wins overall and so a z-test. (If you want to pursue that I can give more details)

The more general alternative (that the distribution from which your individual bernoullis-with-different-$p$'s come is not identical to the hypothesized one) is a little harder, but could be done using, for example, a chi-square-type or a G-type statistic on each individual trial (perhaps with a simulated distribution to find the p-value), or you could bin them into small intervals (with 3000 of them, say 1% wide) and simulate the distribution of such a statistic on that setup under the null.

Comment: Thanks. The number of expected wins is obvious - just the sum of the probabilities, but could you give more details on how to calculate the variance of total wins for such a z-test? My stats is pretty rusty...

Comment: Under the null, the individual trials are [Bernoulli($p_i$)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) and they're independent so the variance of the sum of the 0's and 1's will be the sum of the individual variances. The resulting distribution of the sum is called the [Poisson-Binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) and the mean and variance results are given there.

Comment: For large enough $n$ (as long as the typical $p_i$'s are not *too* small) the standardized version of a random variable with this distribution ($Z = (S - \mu_S)/\sigma_S$) can be well approximated as a standard normal (though I'd use a continuity correction!).

Answer (score 0):

I would also have a glance to the calibration plot of caret R package. If you data set is dataset, you can encode Outcome as factor and plot a calibration plot:

```
dataset$Outcome<-factor(dataset$Outcome, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("N","Y"), ordered=TRUE) #encoding in factor
mycalibration<-calibration(Outcome~Prob, data=dataset, class="Y)
plot(calibration) #standard plot using lattice
ggplot(calibration) #plot using ggplot2 (also showing binomial c.i.)
```

A calibration plot basically divides your data in buckets of predicted probabilities and plots the actual vs the predicted outcomes (ref. class='Y'). See the cuts option to specify the either the number or the single probs.